# getting error in vine upload

Tags: ios, video, vine

I m uploading Video On vine App following this Link:https://github.com/VineAPI/VineAPI/blob/master/endpoints.md.
 Video Succesfully uploaded. but When Open the Vine app my Iphone6 and goto  My post view , Uploaded Video not show in My post.

I m Using This:`PUT - https://media.vineapp.com/upload/videos/1.3.1.mp4

```
Host:              media.vineapp.com
Proxy-Connection:  keep-alive
Content-Type:      video/mp4
X-Vine-Client:     ios/1.3.1
Content-Length:    312112
Accept-Language:   en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
Accept:            */*
vine-session-id:   key
Accept-Encoding:   gzip, deflate
Connection:        keep-alive
User-Agent:        iphone/1.3.1 (iPad; iOS 6.1.3; Scale/1.00)

+
RAW video`
```